# KeePass Sync overrides entry modified by two users

Tags: sync, keepass

I am new to KeePass and would use it with multiple Users. But the entrys get overridden with old data from the other User.

1. User A and User B open the same database file from an shared
   storage.
2. User A modifies entry "Test" and saves the DB
3. User B opens the same entry "Test" and and gets the old values displayed because no syn has taken place yet
4. User B modifies the entry "Test" (same or different field) and saves the DB.
5. User B sees the dialog to "synchronize" or "override" and clicks
   "synchronize" (https://keepass.info/screenshots/windows_vista/syncorsave_big.png)
6. Both users closes the database.
7. The changes from user A are "lost" because the whole entry with old data from user B overwritten the new data from User A

The changes from step 2 and 4 should be merged after all or at least a conflict warning should appear. Am i holding it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> User A modifies entry "Test" and saves the DB Then User B modifies the
> entry "Test" .... saves the DB....sees the dialog to "synchronize" or
> "override" and clicks "synchronize"

It is very important that the DB be saved by the first user before the second user opens it.

Make sure users have equal access to the shared DB at the same time and that the DB is on a folder / drive that provides this equal access.

I am pretty sure A needs to synchronize first so B sees the changes. Certainly try this.

KeePass works out of the registry for its data, so saving and synchronizing by the first user is important so the second user sees the changes.

Comment: Both User are using the same DB File. So if User A saved the data, it is in the DB File. Sync should not be necsessary (i've tried it, doesn't changes the behavior)

Comment: Make sure the DB has actually been saved before the other user opens it. I find I must be sure of this to get my DB to my iPhone.  If the DB has been saved then next user will get the changes

Comment: KeePass offers Multiuser access https://keepass.info/help/base/multiuser.html#syncorsave2x So thins can't be the solution. A User doesn't know when the others have changed something.

Comment: Even so, a user must commit changes before another user access the same database.

Comment: Also I assume you are using KeePass V2.85.1

Comment: I dont get it. The DB is saved after each change. And additional synchronising by User A doesn't changed the behavior. What do you mean? Only one User at the same time have the DB open? All Users syncronising every time before doing changes?

Comment: We have KeePass 2.48 (2.48.1) released 2021-05-07 14:34. I don't see a version 2.85.1

Comment: My error - you are correct. 2.48.1  is most recent.